# What is the difference between ACARS and ADS-B?

Tags: weather, avionics, ads-b, acars

What is the difference between ACARS and ADS-B?

For weather information in-flight or pre-flight which one is used?

Comment: They're two separate protocols. ADS-B is used for transponder reporting and TCAS; ACARS is for relaying information from the company (airline) to pilots.

Comment: Are you referring to FIS-B, rather than ADS-B?

Comment: You may add your current understanding of both systems so that we can adapt the answer to address the points unclear to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can easily get lost in the alphabet soup that is datalink.

Both ACARS and ADS-B provide datalink applications – which can be broken down in terms of CNS: **C**ommunication, **N**avigation, and **S**urveillance.

- ACARS is used for:

  - Communication: includes uplinking (ground → aircraft) **weather** data upon a downlink request to the company/service provider – not a public service
  - Navigation: if you consider flex-routing
  - Surveillance: position reports in the North Atlantic for example ([CPDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller%E2%80%93pilot_data_link_communications) over ACARS).
- ADS-B is used solely for Surveillance; broadcasting (OUT) own location – and can include ownship surveillance by receiving (IN) traffic information.

  - If this IN setup is via the UAT frequency, then the aircraft can also receive **weather** information using [FIS-B](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/adsb/pilot/#fisb) (free service). Its only relation to ADS-B *in this particular instance* is the UAT frequency, and it is more of a general aviation (and low-flying commercial) service.

[image]
Source: https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/adsb/pilot/#fisb

Comment: Link has been moved to https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/adsb